# How to create a static/grainy animation effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects, adobe-after-effects

I don't know what to call this but this kind of grain/static (almost like an old TV) showed up when I created a low quality gif of an animation- see the sky and little particle bits emitting: https://dribbble.com/shots/5297810-Dystopian-game-preview-low-res

[image]

How would you create this in AfterEffects over a static image?

Comment: https://aescripts.com/retrodither/ ?

Comment: It's merely a heavily dithered gif.

Comment: @Scott so the effect is called dithering? I want to apply it on purpose

Answer (score 1):

Open an image, and click *Image > Mode > Indexed Color*

Set the dither to *Diffusion*, amount *100%*

[image]

Afterwards, you can convert back to RGB colour mode. The effect will still remain.